# Creating FW/1 Service in application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, application.cfc, fw1

I am trying to create call a service in application.cfc

The original code looked like

It is now

```
void function setupApplication() {

  ...
  application.objCCFRO  = new model.services.setting();
  application.stSetting = application.objCCFRO.loadini("standard.ini");
```

I am trying to convert it to

```
  application.stSetting = variables.beanFactory.getBean( "settingService" ).loadIni("standard.ini");
```

The documentation says

> sometimes you need access to the bean factory directly (such as for
>   obtaining a transient) and whilst you can get at it inside your
>   controllers via `variables.fw.getBeanFactory()` it’s better to have the
>   bean factory injected by declaring property beanFactory; (which can be
>   used in both controllers and services), then you can call
>   `variables.beanFactory.getBean()` whenevr [sic] you need a transient.

I need a transient when I run `setupApplication()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're using DI/1 with FW/1, you can set `accessors="true"` in your Application.cfc and then define `property settingService;`. This will make the service available, via `variables.settingService`, providing that DI/1 is managing that CFC.

Your example call could then become: `application.stSetting = variables.settingService.loadIni("standard.ini");`

Comment: Indeed. Depending on the situation, I typically hold back from a direct call to the bean factory unless I need metadata available from its own functions or I'm digging into a factory not available to the current controller/service's own factory.